# switch stylesheet flicker

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site with 2 stylesheets, one for day and one for night reading. I have an image with an `onclick` event to call a function to change the stylesheet. The problem is, for new visitors, when they first click the button, the page goes to completely unstyled (i.e. no stylesheet) just for half a second, then the new one kicks in. I know the reason this is happening is that I remove the `rel="stylesheet"` of the current sheet before adding it to the new one. Is there any way I can improve the function so that there is no brief delay, even for new visitors? Thanks.

```
function changeStyleSheet() {
    var a = document.getElementById('stylesheet1');
    var b = document.getElementById('stylesheet2');
    var now1 = $(a).attr('rel');
    var now2 = $(b).attr('rel');
    if (now1 == 'stylesheet') {
        a.setAttribute('rel', 'alt-stylesheet');
        b.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    } else {
        b.setAttribute('rel', 'alt-stylesheet');
        a.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried switching the order of setting the attributes? Like set the rel attribute of the stylesheet you are switching to first and then set the rel attribute of the stylesheet you are switching away from after?

Set both rel attributes to stylesheet in the HTML, and when the page loads use javascript to change one of them to alternative stylesheet.

Comment: No, I have not...let me try. I didn't orginally because I thought I couldn't have `rel="stylesheet"` set to two elements at once.

Comment: Didn't make a difference. It _seems_ that the browser is taking a short moment to load the second stylesheet or something like that. Because that when I have switched the sheets once it does not flicker any more.

Comment: Then how about preloading the stylesheets. Set both of the rel attributes to stylesheet in the html and when the page loads have the javascript switch one of them to alternate stylesheet.

Comment: The last suggestion seems like it has worked...though Opera is still acting in its own stupid way. Put another answer so I can check it as correct (the current one is not).

Comment: I've edited the answer to include setting the rel attribute in the HTML and then changing it with the javascript once it loads.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have one something along these lines:

JavaScript

```
function changeStyle() {
    document.getElementById('stylesheet').href = 'style2.css';
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" onclick="changeStyle();"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" id="stylesheet">
```

OR try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/ZqtPs/) for multiple stylesheets

For toggle try this:

```
function changeStyle() {
    var a = document.getElementById('stylesheet').href;
    if (a === 'style1.css') {
        document.getElementById('stylesheet').href = 'style2.css';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('stylesheet').href = 'style1.css';        
    }
}​
```

Comment: That looks easier. But how would you switch it back, as in a toggle?

Comment: Wrap it in an if function, gimme a sec

Comment: Ok, tried that. It isn't working. Do I need to call both of the sheets in the head tag still? If so, do I put `rel` and `id` on them. I could see a problem if I have two with the same id (wrong) and the function is looking for one.

Comment: The problem is that with the multiple elements it is dependent on the `JavaScript:changeSheets(#)` part which is individually defined in the links. I have one button that must do both.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not required to maintain two separate stylesheets, then it might be easier to achieve your aim by simply applying an `id` to a parent element within the `body`. In my demo, I've used the `body` element for simplicity, but if that's not possible you could simply wrap the contents of your site in a `div` and add an `id` to that. Then it's simply a matter of prefacing your CSS selectors with the relevant `id` to apply the relevant styles.

In my demo I'm using the following JavaScript:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('styles'),
    b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
sel.onchange = function() {
    b.id = this.value;
};​
```

And CSS:

```
#styles1 h1 {
    margin-top: 1em;
    color: #f00;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
}

#styles1 div {
    width: 80%;
}

#styles2 h1 {
    margin-top: 1em;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-style: italic;
}

#styles2 div {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
}

/* the following is for the element holding the style-switcher select */
#styles1 #themes,
#styles2 #themes {
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2JPBZ/).

With the above, you shouldn't notice any flickers when the styles change, because the stylesheet is already loaded. If your page is particularly complex there might be a visible flicker, but it *should* be far more brief than the flicker from switching to a new stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your two stylesheets have a very similar structure, you're going to end up with an odd flicker/render anyway:

Order of change (you're hoping for):

- sheet 1 - applied
- sheet 2 - applied
- sheet 1 - removed

That means that for a brief second, you'll have both style sheets applied (not a problem if they're both just setting a color palette and all on the same elements, but will be a problem if more verbose/significant).

If this is a problem, you might think about doing something to make the style sheet change look awesome - like fading out the page/elements before the style change, change the style, and then fade back in.

If it's not a concern, you should be able to use the approach provided by jacktheripper